# Removing vowels from a string.

Tags: c, string, character-encoding, fgets

I'm trying to read a string from stdin and substitute the vowels on the string by '_'.
Off course it's simple, but I want to substitute the accented vowels too. Obviously the following code doesn't work for those cases. I've tryied several things, like read char by char but and it to a short, consider the cases where line[i]<0, etc.

```
while(fgets(line, 250, stdin)){
    size=strlen(line);
    for(i=0;i<size;i++){
        if(line[i]==65 || line[i]==69 ||line[i]==73 ||line[i]==79 ||line[i]==85 ||line[i]==97 ||line[i]==101 ||line[i]==105 ||line[i]==111 ||line[i]==117){
            line[i]='_';
        }
     }
}
```

Any suggestions? Thank you in advance.

Ps: Consider the used encoding is Western (ISO-8859-1) -> http://www.alanwood.net/demos/ansi.html

Comment: You do know that the magic number `65` doesn't *have* to be upper-case `'A'`? So why not simply use the character literal `'A'` which will always be the upper-case letter `'A'`.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I know, but that's not the problem I presented...

Comment: The question is: how do I process the accented characters? How can I identify them?

Comment: @user1916860, Given that you have a specific code page to work with, you can use that page's character codes. Or you could use a Unicode library that supports this code page.

Comment: @chris I've tryied, without sucess...

Comment: It would be helpful if you could explain what isn't working.  What would you like your code to be able to do that it is not doing currently?

Comment: @dohashi currenty, my code only substitutes the non-accented vowels, and I want it to substitute the accented vowels also. Even if I compare using the enconding I refered, the program simply ignores de accented vowels and does nothing in those cases, just prints the accented vowel normally.

Comment: The code you posted makes no attempt to substitute the accented vowels.  Show us what you tried, and maybe someone can tell you why it didn't work.

Comment: for example, I tryied adding the comparison line[i]==201 (line[i]=='É') without results. I'm now trying to read char by char using the following:



     unsigned letter;
     while(scanf("%02x", &letter))...

Comment: Note, one way to figure this out is to create a string of accented vowels, and then print the values with `for(i=0;i<strlen(str);i++) printf("%c %d\n", str[i], str[i]);`. That should tell you what the numbers are.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably running into a signed vs unsigned character issue.  The ANSI values for the accented characters show on the link you provided are larger that the max size of an signed char.  This is probably why you are seeing negative character values as well.

If you want to fix this properly, I'd suggest using a wide character format and character constants.

If you want something quick and easy, add the following in your for loop to see how the characters are mapping to values:

```
printf( "%c %d\n", line[i], (int)line[i] );
```

Then add the appropriate values to your if.

Comment: The `%s` should be `%c`, but otherwise, yes

Comment: I'll fix that.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I used the following data
**htyuàsdsècvcvcàdìssd**

and the following code works with accented characters. The result was **htyu_sds_cvcvc_d_ssd**

```
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <wchar.h>
   #include <locale.h>
   int main(int argc, char **argv){
      setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "UTF-8");
      FILE *f = fopen("/Users/sandeepshabd/objectiveC/C_TEST_App/C_TEST_App/file.txt",  "r, ccs=UTF-8");
if (!f)
    return 1;

for (wchar_t c; (c = fgetwc(f)) != WEOF;){
    switch (c) {
        case L'à': c=L'_'; break;
        case L'è': c=L'_';break;
        case L'é': c=L'_';break;
        case L'ì': c=L'_';break;
        case L'ò': c=L'_';break;
        case L'ù': c=L'_';break;
        default:    break;
    }
    wprintf(L"%c", c);
}


fclose(f);
return 0;
```

}

Comment: This will not work because the ascii characters are 8 bits not 16 bits, so many/most characters will fail.  simply use something like getc, which returns an int, and compare only on the lower 8 bits.

Comment: We are talking about Latin characters here. Isn't that UTF 8 supports Latin characters ? I understand when we may for other International character sets, things may not work. [UTF-8 Latin Support](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/)

Comment: @user3629249: There are no accented vowels among ASCII characters.